# If statement loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

So I made a program to do different math problems depending on what the user wants, and I don't want the program to end after the user is done. Right now, the loop I have just repeats the same option over and over. The desired effect is to be able to keep choosing which problem you want to do. I am fairly new to coding so I apologize if this is a simple question.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("What problem do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("1:Celcius to Farenheit");
    System.out.println("2:Slope Formula");
    System.out.println("3:Averages");
    System.out.println("4:Perimeter");
    System.out.println("5:Exit\n\n");
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int response = keyboard.nextInt();

    
    do
    {
    if (response == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Degrees Celcius:");
        int degrees = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(degrees + " degrees Celcius is " + celsToFarenheit(degrees) + " degrees Farenheit.");
    }
    else if (response == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("x1:");
        int x1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("y1:");
        int y1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("x2:");
        int x2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("y2:");
        int y2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The slope is " + slopeFormula(x1,y1,x2,y2));
    }
    else if (response == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("First number:");
        int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Second number:");
        int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The average is " + average(num1,num2));
    }
    else if (response == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Length:");
        int length = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Width:");
        int width = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The perimeter is " + perimeter(length,width));
    }
}
while (response != 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this bit like this:

```
do
{
int response = keyboard.nextInt();
if (response == 1)
```

If you move the `keyboard.nextInt()` call to inside the `do` loop it will now repeatedly ask the user for input.

You had this line of code **before** the loop so it only processed once.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int response` outside of the loop.  Inside the loop place `response = keyboard.nextInt();`

With `int response = keyboard.nextInt()` outside of the loop, you never reach it again.  Also, place the options inside the loop so they will display each time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int response;


    do {
        System.out.println("What problem do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("1:Celcius to Farenheit");
        System.out.println("2:Slope Formula");
        System.out.println("3:Averages");
        System.out.println("4:Perimeter");
        System.out.println("5:Exit\n\n");

        response = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (response == 1) {
            System.out.println("Degrees Celcius:");
            int degrees = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println(degrees + " degrees Celcius is " + celsToFarenheit(degrees) + " degrees Farenheit.");
        } else if (response == 2) {
            System.out.println("x1:");
            int x1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("y1:");
            int y1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("x2:");
            int x2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("y2:");
            int y2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The slope is " + slopeFormula(x1,y1,x2,y2));
        } else if (response == 3) {
            System.out.println("First number:");
            int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Second number:");
            int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The average is " + average(num1,num2));
        } else if (response == 4) {
            System.out.println("Length:");
            int length = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Width:");
            int width = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The perimeter is " + perimeter(length,width));
        }
    }
    while (response != 5);
}
```